# Substitution code working one way but not in reverse

Tags: java, arrays, substitution

I'm trying to make a simple "translation" project as i'm still learning java. But something went wrong and I've spent many hours and still no idea how to fix it. Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
 {

  char[] abcCode = {'!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','_','-','+','=','|','`','~','}','{','[',']','"',';',':','>','<','?','/','\''};

  char[] numCode = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','x','y','z'};


  String src = args[0];
  String result = "";


  for(int i=0; i < src.length();i++)
  {
   char ch = src.charAt(i); 
   if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') 
    result += abcCode[ch-'a']; 
   else if (abcCode[0] <= ch && ch <= abcCode[15])
    result += numCode[ch-abcCode[0]];

  }

  System.out.println("src: "+src);
  System.out.println("result: "+result);}}
```

For example if I type "lol" I will get "-|-", which is what I want. But the opposite never works, I'm supposed to type -|- and get "lol". Also if I type "@" and a few others I will get an error. What's the problem? Any lights?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the abcCode array is populated with things which, when converted to numbers, do not start at one value and go up by one in successive elements.  I put the following code just after the declaration of the arrays:

```
   for (char c: abcCode)
   {
     System.out.println(c - args[0].charAt(0));
   }
   return;
```

and got the following output:

> -91
>   -60
>   -89
>   -88
>   -87
>   -30
>   -86
>   -82
>   -84
>   -83
>   -29
>   -79
>   -81
>   -63 0
>   -28 2 1
>   -1
>   -33
>   -31
>   -90
>   -65
>   -66
>   -62
>   -64
>   -61
>   -77
>   -85

(In my output, each number was on a different line, but I've forgotten how to force that here in the answer.)

As you can see, the resulting numbers are not valid indices into the other array.